# How to get an output dimension for each layer of the Neural Network in Pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

```
class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 16), 
      nn.ReLU(), 
      nn.MaxPool2d(2),
      nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 16, out_channels = 16), 
      nn.ReLU(),
      Flatten(),
      nn.Linear(4096, 64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(64, 10))

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.net(x)
```

I have created this model without a firm knowledge in Neural Network and I just fixed parameters until it worked in the training. I am not sure how to get the output dimension for each layer (e.g. output dimension after the first layer).

Is there an easy way to do this in Pytorch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model summary in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480111/model-summary-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple way is:

1. Pass the input to the model.
2. Print the size of the output after passing every layer.

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Model, self).__init__()
    self.net = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 16), 
      nn.ReLU(), 
      nn.MaxPool2d(2),
      nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 16, out_channels = 16), 
      nn.ReLU(),
      Flatten(),
      nn.Linear(4096, 64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(64, 10))

  def forward(self, x):
    for layer in self.net:
        x = layer(x)
        print(x.size())
    return x

model = Model()
x = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Let's print it
model(x)
```

> But be careful with the input size because you are using `nn.Linear` in your net. It would cause incompatible input size for nn.Linear if your input size is not `4096`.

Comment: What's the (1, 3, 244, 244) ?

Comment: just create a pseudo example of input: `x = torch.randn(1, 3, 244, 244)`

Comment: what i have multiple networks in my model and multiple inputs and some of the inputs look something like torch.Size([20,16000])?

Answer (score 31):

You can use torchsummary, for instance, for ImageNet dimension(3x224x224):

```
from torchvision import models
from torchsummary import summary

vgg = models.vgg16()
summary(vgg, (3, 224, 224)


----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 224, 224]           1,792
              ReLU-2         [-1, 64, 224, 224]               0
            Conv2d-3         [-1, 64, 224, 224]          36,928
              ReLU-4         [-1, 64, 224, 224]               0
         MaxPool2d-5         [-1, 64, 112, 112]               0
            Conv2d-6        [-1, 128, 112, 112]          73,856
              ReLU-7        [-1, 128, 112, 112]               0
            Conv2d-8        [-1, 128, 112, 112]         147,584
              ReLU-9        [-1, 128, 112, 112]               0
        MaxPool2d-10          [-1, 128, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-11          [-1, 256, 56, 56]         295,168
             ReLU-12          [-1, 256, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-13          [-1, 256, 56, 56]         590,080
             ReLU-14          [-1, 256, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-15          [-1, 256, 56, 56]         590,080
             ReLU-16          [-1, 256, 56, 56]               0
        MaxPool2d-17          [-1, 256, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-18          [-1, 512, 28, 28]       1,180,160
             ReLU-19          [-1, 512, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-20          [-1, 512, 28, 28]       2,359,808
             ReLU-21          [-1, 512, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-22          [-1, 512, 28, 28]       2,359,808
             ReLU-23          [-1, 512, 28, 28]               0
        MaxPool2d-24          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-25          [-1, 512, 14, 14]       2,359,808
             ReLU-26          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-27          [-1, 512, 14, 14]       2,359,808
             ReLU-28          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-29          [-1, 512, 14, 14]       2,359,808
             ReLU-30          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
        MaxPool2d-31            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
           Linear-32                 [-1, 4096]     102,764,544
             ReLU-33                 [-1, 4096]               0
          Dropout-34                 [-1, 4096]               0
           Linear-35                 [-1, 4096]      16,781,312
             ReLU-36                 [-1, 4096]               0
          Dropout-37                 [-1, 4096]               0
           Linear-38                 [-1, 1000]       4,097,000
================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.57
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 218.59
Params size (MB): 527.79
Estimated Total Size (MB): 746.96
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Source: [model-summary-in-pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480111/model-summary-in-pytorch)

Comment: What's the (3, 244, 244) ?

Comment: @Dawn17 It's the dimensions of a single image (for MNIST it is 1x28x28)

Comment: I am getting this error `RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 3, 3, 3], but got 5-dimensional input of size [2, 1, 3, 224, 224] instead` What size do I have to put?

Comment: @Dawn17 I need to see your code to assist you, but I guess that you run in your network MNIST which is 1x28x28 and VGG input is 3x224x224. So, first in the forward method try to reshape it like: 'out.view(out.shape[0], -1)'
and second, change the model to yours instead of the VGG in my example.

Comment: For new visitors to this question, please note that torchsummary is now renamed to torchinfo in PIP: https://pypi.org/project/torchinfo/.

Answer (score 6):

Like David Ng's answer but a tad shorter:

```py
def get_output_shape(model, image_dim):
    return model(torch.rand(*(image_dim))).data.shape
```

In this example I needed to figure out the input of the last Linear layer:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.expected_input_shape = (1, 1, 192, 168)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1) 
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(3)

        # Calculate the input of the Linear layer
        conv1_out = get_output_shape(self.maxpool1, get_output_shape(conv1, self.expected_input_shape))
        conv2_out = get_output_shape(self.maxpool2, get_output_shape(conv2, conv1_out)) 
        fc1_in = np.prod(list(conv2_out)) # Flatten

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(fc1_in, 38)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x) 
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x) 
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x) 
        x = self.dropout1(x) 
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten to a single dimension
        x = self.fc1(x) 
        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1) 
        return output
```

This way, if I make changes to previous layers, I won't have to calculate all over again!

My answer is based on [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/linear-layer-input-neurons-number-calculation-after-conv2d/28659/3)

Answer (score 6):

```
for layer in model.children():
    if hasattr(layer, 'out_features'):
        print(layer.out_features)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get the size after a certain layer in an `nn.Sequential` container is to add a custom `Module` that just prints out the size of the input.

```py
class PrintSize(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(PrintSize, self).__init__()
    
  def forward(self, x):
    print(x.shape)
    return x
```

And now you can do:

```py
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 10, 5, 1),
    // lots of convolutions, pooling, etc.
    nn.Flatten(),
    PrintSize(),
    nn.Linear(1, 12), // the input dim of 1 is just a placeholder
)
```

Now, you can do `model(x)` and it will print out the shape of the output after the `Conv2d` layer ran. This is useful if you have a lot of convolutions and want to figure out what the final dimensions are for the first fully connected layer. You don't need to reformat your `nn.Sequential` as a Module and can just drop in this helper class with one-line.

Comment: If we do not want to change existing model then layer.register_forward_hook is better

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in the form of a helper function:

```
def get_tensor_dimensions_impl(model, layer, image_size, for_input=False):
    t_dims = None
    def _local_hook(_, _input, _output):
        nonlocal t_dims
        t_dims = _input[0].size() if for_input else _output.size()
        return _output    
    layer.register_forward_hook(_local_hook)
    dummy_var = torch.zeros(1, 3, image_size, image_size)
    model(dummy_var)
    return t_dims
```

Example:

```
from torchvision import models, transforms

a_model = models.squeezenet1_0(pretrained=True) 
get_tensor_dimensions_impl(a_model, a_model._modules['classifier'], 224)
```

Output is:

> torch.Size([1, 1000, 1, 1])

Answer (score 1):

Inspire by @minggli answer, I used the model's children.

This method will have some steps to modify if not all of the steps are actually in the model's children (e.g. in the ex below a `torch.flatten` call is in the ResNet18 model's forward method but not in the model's children list).

```
device = "cuda" # if you want to put on gpu
model = torchvision_models.resnet18(weights="IMAGENET1K_V1")
model.to(device)
batch_size = 4
n_bands = 3
n_rows = 224
n_cols = 224
ex_input = torch.ones((batch_size, n_bands, n_rows, n_cols), device=device)

for i,c in enumerate(list(model.children())):
    # per source code it looks like there is a flatten call which is not in 
    # model.children() & so will need to be added here to get this method to work
    if i == 0:
        layer_output = c(ex_input)
    else:
        if c.__str__() == 'Linear(in_features=512, out_features=10, bias=True)':
            print('layer found')
            print("\t before flatten", layer_output.shape)
            layer_output = torch.flatten(layer_output, 1)
            print("\t after flatten", layer_output.shape)

        layer_output = c(layer_output)

    print(f"children index {i}: {c}")
    print("\t",layer_output.shape)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I wrote:

```
total_output_elements = 0
def calc_total_activation_size(model, call_the_network_function):
    global total_output_elements
    total_output_elements = 0

    def hook(module, input, output):
        global total_output_elements
        total_output_elements += output.numel()
        
    handle = torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_hook(hook)
    result = call_the_network_function()
    handle.remove()
    return result, total_output_elements
```

In the hook, you can print the output.shape

The parameters:
model - your model
call_the_network_function - a function that calls the forward pass of your model, and return the result

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try `print(model.state_dict()['next_layer.weight'].shape)`.
This gives you a hint of the output shape from last layer.