# pytorch model summary - forward func has more than one argument

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using torch summary

```
from torchsummary import summary
```

I want to pass more than one argument when printing the model summary, but the examples mentioned here: [Model summary in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56762410/5082406) taken only one argument. for e.g.:

```
model = Network().to(device)
summary(model,(1,28,28))
```

The reason is that the forward function takes two arguments as input, e.g.:

```
def forward(self, img1, img2):
```

How do I pass two arguments here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the example given here: [pytorch summary multiple inputs](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary#multiple-inputs)

```
summary(model, [(1, 16, 16), (1, 28, 28)])
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: Does this work there are multiple dtypes for your model arguments? like arg1 -> float, arg2 -> long?

Answer (score 0):

It works by modifying codes on line 10 of torchsummary.py.

Instead of this:

```
total_input_size = abs(np.prod(input_size) * batch_size * 4. / (1024 ** 2.))
```

use this:

```
total_input_size = abs(np.prod(input_size[0]) * batch_size * 4. / (1024 ** 2.))
```

My torchsummary.py version is 1.5.1. I guess the author of the gadget should update his jewel for two inputs to a model. For example, in summary(model, [(3, 256, 256), (256,256)]), the gadget should use (3,256,256) in the list for two inputs.