# missing 1 required positional argument, in model summary

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I tried to print the summary of the SinGAN model, but I got an error which is:

[image]
This is the code:

```
def init_models(opt):

#generator initialization:
netG = models.GeneratorConcatSkip2CleanAdd(opt).to(opt.device)
netG.apply(models.weights_init)
if opt.netG != '':
    netG.load_state_dict(torch.load(opt.netG))
summary(netG,input_size=(3, 201, 256))
print(netG)

#discriminator initialization:
netD = models.WDiscriminator(opt).to(opt.device)
netD.apply(models.weights_init)
if opt.netD != '':
    netD.load_state_dict(torch.load(opt.netD))
print(netD)

return netD, netG
```

The problem when i add this line:

```
    summary(netG,input_size=(3, 201, 256))
```

And I get the complete code from [here](https://github.com/dvschultz/ai/blob/master/SinGAN.ipynb).

So, is my way wrong? should I use a different variable as a model?

Comment: where have you imported the `summary` from ? Check its documentation. You are probably using the argument name (`input_size`) wrong, as that tensor is not being passed into model

Comment: I imported the `summary` using this command `from torchsummary import summary` and I tried to use `input_size` and deleted it but i got same problem

Answer (score 1):

[The forward function of your model](https://github.com/tamarott/SinGAN/blob/286d3cd51cc327381737844d330348ec97577e60/SinGAN/models.py#L57) expects two input images. In `torchsummary.summary`, you are providing only one input shape, so it is trying to pass only one input image to your model, leaving the second required argument unpassed and hence raising the issue. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60480687/10127204) how to pass inputs to `torchsummary.summary` when model expects multiple inputs in the `forward` method.