# Pytorch model summary - forward func has more than one argument. One argument is an integer

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using torch summary. I want to pass more than one argument when printing the model summary, one of which is just an integer. However, I get an error. I follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480686/pytorch-model-summary-forward-func-has-more-than-one-argument) recommendation but it is not working.

My network looks like

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchsummary import summary


class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
 
  def forward(self, x,t):
    return t * x
```

I tried to run summary as `summary(model,[(3, 64, 64),(1)])`
and got `TypeError: rand() argument after * must be an iterable, not int`.

"Solved" that by doing `summary(model,[(3, 64, 64),(1,)])`
but still get another `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'`.

How can I get the model summary then?

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `(3, 64, 64),(1)` to `(3, 64, 64),(1,)` helped because all the elements of list should be `Tuple` type.
However when it tries to run forward it cannot perform multiplication of tuple by tuple (because it is not possible in any python code).

You can change from `Tuple` to `torch.Tensor`
`summary(model,[torch.Tensor((3, 64, 64)),torch.Tensor((1,))])`

Comment: Still not working with that modification. I get `TypeError: rand(): argument 'size' must be tuple of ints, but found element of type Tensor at pos 2`. It happens when summary tries to create an input using `x = [torch.rand(2, *in_size).type(dtype) for in_size in input_size]` which was the same line that got me into troubles when I used `(3, 64, 64),(1)`.