# How can i know the architecture of pre-trained model in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, face-recognition, arcface

I have downloaded this pre-trained model "model_ir_se50.pth" for face recognition. It is giving very good results. How can i know its architecture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model summary in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480111/model-summary-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

simple `print(net) #replace net with the network variable` will work as per your need.

Comment: you mean like this : `import torch 
pretrained = torch.load("model_ir_se50.pth")
print(pretrained.net()) `

Comment: `print(pretrained)`

Comment: Its output is very big..but you can get an idea from a part of it i am pasting. OrderedDict([('input_layer.0.weight', tensor([[[[ 5.0732e-02,  6.5002e-03,  1.9098e-02],....

Comment: can you edit your post and add the code which you are using to get the results.