# Print Bert model summary using Pytorch

Tags: input, model, pytorch, bert-language-model, summary

Hi I would like to print the model summary of my BERT model for text classification. I am using command print(summary(model, inputsize=(channels, height, width)). I would like to know what would be the dimensions of input_size in case of text classification?
I have use print(model) as well but the output is confusing and I want to see the output in the layered form.
Below is my model summary.

```
BertClassifier(
  (bert): BertModel(
    (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
      (word_embeddings): Embedding(28996, 768, padding_idx=0)
      (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
      (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
      (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
      (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    )
    (encoder): BertEncoder(
      (layer): ModuleList(
        (0): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (1): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (2): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (3): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (4): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (5): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (6): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (7): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (8): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (9): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (10): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
        (11): BertLayer(
          (attention): BertAttention(
            (self): BertSelfAttention(
              (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
            (output): BertSelfOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          )
          (output): BertOutput(
            (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
            (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
          )
        )
      )
    )
    (pooler): BertPooler(
      (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (activation): Tanh()
    )
  )
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (linear1): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=256, bias=True)
  (linear2): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=141, bias=True)
  (relu): ReLU()
)
```

Comment: inputsize=(channels, height, width)???? What do you think? It's an Image Classification Model?

Comment: yes, In the case of image classification height and width are the respective to image size. I would like to know in case of Text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model summary in pytorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480111/model-summary-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used torch-summary module-

```
pip install torch-summary

summary(model,input_size=(768,),depth=1,batch_dim=1, dtypes=[‘torch.IntTensor’])
```

Answer (score 0):

minor supplement to @Flash, to import summary library

```
from torchsummary import summary
```